# Two Buttons Within Form

Tags: jquery, html

there seems to be some weird behavior with two buttons within my form. Whenever the 'Add Address' button is clicked, the event handler executes properly but after it's finished, it also executes the 'Submit' button's event handler as well.

The code for the buttons is as follows:

```
<button class="btn btn-success" id="add-address">Add Address</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

I can get around this problem by changing the first button into a `span` element Eg:

```
<span class="btn btn-success" id="add-address">Add Address</span>
```

Everything works fine once this change is made. Can someone please explain this behavior? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default all `button` elements are `submit` buttons. You need to add `type="button"` to the first one to stop it raising a submit event on the parent `form` element on click.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-address">Add Address</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help! I never knew that `button` elements default to `type=submit`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be as below

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="add-address">Add Address</button>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

*Always specify the type attribute for the `<button>` element. Different browsers may use different default types for the `<button>` element.*

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_type.asp

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much for your help! Never knew that I should always specify the type attribute.

Comment: Please note that the "Different browsers" bit refers to very old versions of IE, and that all browsers behave the same today, keeping to the W3C standards of defaulting to "submit".